# Unable to run JavaFx Jar with JRE7

Tags: javafx-2, java

I am trying to run JavaFx Jar with reference of JRE but it is showing error message and throwing this IOException -

```
C:\Users\JavaUser4\Desktop\New folder (2)>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.e
xe" -jar ABCTemp.jar
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is inc
orrect
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
        at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(Unknown Source)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.fileToURL(Main.java:97)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.findLaunchMethod(Main.java:152)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.findLaunchMethodInJar(Main.java:210)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.findLaunchMethod(Main.java:712)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:803)
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is inc
orrect
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
        at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(Unknown Source)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.fileToURL(Main.java:97)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.findLaunchMethod(Main.java:152)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.findLaunchMethodInJar(Main.java:210)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.findLaunchMethod(Main.java:726)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:803)
```

Error Message -

[image]

Comment: it seems like filepath issue! , what version of java you using ? (java -version)

Comment: @invariant java 1.7 Update 9.